# Topological solution for combinatorial geometry problem

Tags: combinatorics, general-topology, discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-proofs, combinatorial-geometry

Let $X$ be a finite set of points in Euclidean plane. It is given that those points are not colinear. i.e. there is no line such that includes all points of $X$. Show that for any function $f \colon X \to \{0,1\}$(coloring the points with 2 color), there is a line $L$ on the plane such that satisfies

(a) $L$ contains at least 2 points in $X$. Namely, $|L \cap X| \geq 2$.

(b) $\forall a,b \in L \cap X$, $f(a) = f(b)$ (all points of $X$ on $L$ have same color).

I reduced this geometric problem in terms of equivalence relation. Let $Y$ be a set of 2-subsets of $X$, and define $Z = \{\{a,b\} \in Y | f(a) = f(b) \}$. Give equivalence relation $\sim$ on $Y$ to be $\{a,b\} \sim \{c,d\}$ iff $a,b,c,d$ are colinear. If $\mathcal{P}$ is a partition induced by $\sim$, then the problem is asking for the existence of $P \in \mathcal{P}$ such that $P \subseteq Z$.

When presenting this problem, my instructor said that combinatorial proof is very complicated, but there is a simple topological proof. Indeed I cannot figure out what to do after the reduction. What are the topological properties that I can exploit to attack this problem? How can I lead to a proof with those properties?

Thanks in advance for every help, hint, or solution.

Comment: side note: induction on the number of points in $X$ offers a fairly swift proof as well

Comment: @KevinS Yes, they are allowed, and in that case, it will have trivial solution. But the problem is asking for $L$ for all $f$, I think.

Comment: In [my other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4073530/177399), I give links to three papers with proofs of this theorem, and summarize one proof in that answer. However, none of the proofs are topological.

Answer (score 1):

[Inductive Proof Has a Problem in the Step Case]

Take $f:X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2\to \{0,1\}$. As discussed, the cases where $f$ is identically $1$ or $0$ hold trivially. So proceed with the assumption that $f$ is *surjective*.

---

$\bullet\text{ }\underline{Base\text{ }Case\text{ }(n=3):}$
If $|X|=3$, $f$ surjective implies:
$$\exists p,q,r\in X:\text{ }f(p) = f(q)\neq f(r).$$
Define:
$$L_{p,q} := \{p+(q-p)t\text{ }|\text{ }t\in \mathbb{R}\}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2.$$
Then $\exists L:= L_{p,q}$ such that $|L\cap X| = |\{p,q\}|=2$ and $f(p)=f(q)$. So $(a)$ and $(b)$ hold for $L$.

---

$\bullet\text{ }\underline{Hypothesis\text{ }Case\text{ }(n=k):}$

Now, *assume true* for fixed $k> 3$. We have a set of points:
$$X := \{p_1,...,p_k\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2,$$
a *surjective* coloring function:
$$f:X\to \{0,1\},$$
and there exists a line:
$$\exists L:= L_{p_ip_j}:= \{p_i+(p_j-p_i)t\text{ }|\text{ }t\in \mathbb{R}\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$$
such that:
$$\forall x,y\in X\cap L:\text{ }f(x)=f(y).$$
Moreover, we have $X\cap L \neq X$ (by assumption all points of $X$ are not on the same line).

---

$\bullet\text{ }\underline{Step\text{ }Case\text{ }(n=k+1):}$
Given the previous case, let us append one more point to $X$. That is:
$$\widetilde{X} := X\cup \{p_{k+1}\}\text{ }\text{ }\text{ and }\text{ }\text{ }Im(\widetilde{f}):= Im(f)\cup\{\widetilde{f}(p_{k+1})\}.$$
If $p_{k+1}\in X$ already, we are done by the previous case.
So let us assume $p_{k+1}\notin X$. Then using (a) in the induction hypothesis, we have
$$\exists L:= L_{p_i,p_j}$$
going through two points $p_i,p_j\in X\subseteq \widetilde{X}$ and using (b) all points in $X\cap L$ have the same color. We need all points in $\widetilde{X}\cap L$ to have the same color to finish the $k+1$ case. The only question now is the state of $p_{k+1}$ (since we have as well not all points of $X$ are colinear implies not all points of $\widetilde{X}$ are colinear). There are four options: $\big(p_{k+1}\in L$ or $p_{k+1}\notin L\big)$ and $\big(\widetilde{f}(p_{k+1}) = 0$ or $1\big)$. 
If $p_{k+1}\notin L$ then $\widetilde{X}\cap L=X\cap L$ and we're done. 
Otherwise, with $p_{k+1}\in L$, success $\color{red}{\text{depends on our choice of extension}}$ for $\widetilde{f}$... [x]

Comment: This is a mess. You've redefined $X$ to include the point $p_{k+1}$ and then you claim success on the basis that $p_{k+1}$ is not in $X$ !

Comment: Good catch, it seems renaming with tildes helped... What happens if we choose a coloring function on all of $\mathbb{R}^2$ instead of $X$?

Comment: Also @mathhello the above is not a disproof, but rather shows how induction would fail. I looked at the equivalence class aspect of it and tried to shoot for a 1st Isomorphism theorem type deal. Namely, $Z= ker(f)$ and theres a quotient space sitting around. But the pieces didn't fit right for me.